# Strange behavior with extra tick style

Tags: pgfplots

The extra y ticks at y = 6000 and y = 5400 and the extra x ticks at x = 24 and x = 20.4 are not drawn.

```
    \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{major grid style={thick,darkgray}}
    \pgfplotsset{minor grid style={lightgray}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
    /pgf/declare function={f(\x)=  1000*(\x +5)*exp(-0.2*\x);}]
    \begin{axis}[
         restrict x to domain=0:22, xmax=22, xmin=0,
         restrict y to domain=0:6000, ymax=6000, ymin=0,
         x=0.6cm,
         y=0.0012cm,
         axis x line=bottom,
         axis y line=left,
         major tick style=black,
         axis line style = ultra thick,
         tick align=outside,
         tickwidth=0.14cm,
         tick style=thick,
         minor x tick num=4,
         minor y tick num=4,
         grid=both,
         xtick={0,2,...,20},
         ytick={0,1000,...,5000},
         y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
         extra x ticks={20.4,20.8,21.2,21.6,22},
         extra x tick label={\null},
         extra y ticks={5200,5400,5600,5800,6000},
         extra y tick label={\null},
         extra x tick style={grid=minor,tick style={draw=none}},
         extra y tick style={grid=minor,tick style={draw=none}},
         xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$,
         every axis x label/.style={
         at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},anchor=west},
         every axis y label/.style={
         at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south},
         samples=3000,
         axis on top=false,
         >=stealth,
         ]
        \addplot [ultra thick,domain=0:20] {f(x)};
        \end{axis}                  
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hm, you declared, that they should not be shown: `extra x tick style={grid=minor,tick style={draw=none}`. if you like to see them, remove `tick style={draw=none}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood correctly what you like to achieve, than you not need `extra ticks`. you only need to define tick labels accordingly:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{major grid style={thick,darkgray}}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={lightgray}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
/pgf/declare function={f(\x)=  1000*(\x +5)*exp(-0.2*\x);}]
\begin{axis}[
     xmax=22, xmin=0,
     ymax=6000, ymin=0,
     x=0.6cm,
     y=0.0012cm,
     axis x line=bottom,
     axis y line=left,
     major tick style=black,
     axis line style = ultra thick,
     tick align=outside,
     tickwidth=0.14cm,
     tick style=thick,
     minor x tick num=4,
     xtick={0,2,...,22},
     xticklabels = {0,2,...,20,},         % <----
     ytick={0,1000,...,6000},
     yticklabels={0,1000,2000,...,5000,},  % <----
     xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$,
     minor y tick num=4,
     grid,
     samples=40,
     >=stealth,
     ]
    \addplot [ultra thick,domain=0:20] {f(x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Zarko Thank you for your suggestion, it's almost the expected result. In fact, the starting code was intended not to draw the last graduation (near the arrow) on each axis.

Answer (score 2):

`xtick={0,2,...,22},
         ytick={0,1000,...,6000}` should allow what you need

unrelated to your question add also `\pgfplotsset{compt=1.15}` int the preamble

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  \pgfplotsset{compt=1.15} % <-------
  \pgfplotsset{major grid style={thick,darkgray}}
  \pgfplotsset{minor grid style={lightgray}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
/pgf/declare function={f(\x)=  1000*(\x +5)*exp(-0.2*\x);}]
\begin{axis}[
     restrict x to domain=0:22, xmax=22, xmin=0,
     restrict y to domain=0:6000, ymax=6000, ymin=0,
     x=0.6cm,
     y=0.0012cm,
     axis x line=bottom,
     axis y line=left,
     major tick style=black,
     axis line style = ultra thick,
     tick align=outside,
     tickwidth=0.14cm,
     tick style=thick,
     minor x tick num=4,
     minor y tick num=4,
     grid=both,
     xtick={0,2,...,22}, % <--------
     ytick={0,1000,...,6000}, % <-----------
     y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
     extra x ticks={20.4,20.8,21.2,21.6,22},
     extra x tick label={\null},
     extra y ticks={5200,5400,5600,5800,6000},
     extra y tick label={\null},
     extra x tick style={grid=minor,tick style={draw=none}},
     extra y tick style={grid=minor,tick style={draw=none}},
     xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$,
     every axis x label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},anchor=west},
     every axis y label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south},
     samples=3000,
     axis on top=false,
     >=stealth,
     ]
    \addplot [ultra thick,domain=0:20] {f(x)};
    \end{axis}                  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]